# How rectify an image from a single calibrated camera using Matlab toolbox

Tags: computer-vision, matlab, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I’m a newbie on computer vision issues, so please forgive me for my standard question.

I´m working on the standard problem: to rectify an image using camera calibrated parameters in order to test the accuracy of the camera calibration. I´m using Jean- Yves Bouget's Camera Calibration Toolbox to calibrate the camera (I used checkerboard-patterns printed on cardboard to do this) and I already have all the camera parameters from the calibration procedure (extrinsic and intrinsic). How can I use these parameters to rectify a new image not in the calibration set?

Thanks in advance..